# How to process auto upload file to Django server

Tags: python, django, upload

Firstly, I am new to use Django, and I am using Django to build a cloud server.
My problem is I know how to build an app for uploading files one by one.

But, I have no any ideas on how to automatically multi-upload files after the client program processed the data; or automatically upload file in client program's procedure.

I google it for few days, but still don't know how to start this part.

Comment: You mean client will initiate multiple uploads at once, log out of the application and come in few days. Meantime, your application will still be uploading file?

Comment: I mean I search the answer for few days, but I have no idea how to start.
I want client program collect the data, and after its process I can upload file automatically.

Comment: take a look at http://www.celeryproject.org/ . It's task system might be what you need to upload multiple files.